# Understanding Total Response

Tags: antenna, closed-loop

[image]QUICK INFO:
I am currently studying about closed and open-loops systems.

BACKGROUND STORY:
Imagine a big antenna is placed on a hill and there is a lot of wind. You want to turn the potentiometer so the antenna turns EXCATLY 65 degrees to the left (just an example) however, the external wind forces (disturbances) turns the antenna additional 2 degrees which leaves you with an antenna that has turned 67 degrees to the left. A closed loop system would subtract the disturbance from the TOTAL RESPONSE (in the input) and make up for the additional two degrees.

QUESTION:
What do you call the response after the subtraction from the TOTAL RESPONSE that your are left with? Furthermore, what would forced response be in this scenario and would natural response be you turning the potentiometer?

Comment: A closed loop system doesn't subtract anything other than the output position from the demanded position in order to produce an error signal that is used to make output = input.

Comment: @Andyaka Then I have understood something wrong. In the textbook "Control_System_Engineering_by_Norman_S_N" on page 8 in chapter one, the author goes on about something called a "summing junction" which "The first summing junction algebraically adds the signal from the input to the
signal from the output, which arrives via the feedback path, the return path from the
output to the summing junction." which for me sounds like a substraction/ addition occuring in the I/O?

Comment: @Andyaka I have a snippet of the closed loop the author is referring to, however, I do not know how to post pictures in here?

Comment: There is a tool that allows you to embed pictures. Edit your question and use the tool.

Comment: The book is referring to the summing node (actually a subtraction node) that converts demand_signal and actual_position_signal to error_signal.

Comment: @Andyaka Done, thank you so much!

Comment: @Andyaka then I quite frankly don't seem to comprehend the text. How does the antenna (assuming it is closed-loop) make up for the two additional degrees?

Comment: The antenna is just an object whose current position is presumably known by using some form of position encoder. The motor that drives the antenna seeks to minimize the error signal. It nor the control system know nothing about a disturbance any more than they know about friction or stiction; they just get on with it.

Comment: @Andyaka Makes sense. However, why does the text state the following then... "The closed-loop system compensates for disturbances by measuring the output
response, feeding that measurement back through a feedback path, and comparing
that response to the input at the summing junction. If there is any difference between
the two responses, the system drives the plant, via the actuating signal, to make a
correction. If there is no difference, the system does not drive the plant, since the
plant’s response is already the desired response."?

Comment: I see absolutely nothing incompatible with that text and what I've been saying. So, what is it that you are having trouble with? Like; are you expecting the control system to measure the disturbance caused by the wind and somehow make an extra compensation?

Comment: @Andyaka You stated that the "control system know nothing about disturbance" which for me sounds like you are stating, that the control system in general can't make up for the disturbances. The text states that a closed loop makes up for disturbance by taking the output and comparing it with the input and hence getting an error/ actuating signal or not. I beg your pardon in advance, I am still new to this topic.

Comment: No, that is not correct. You are not understanding what a control system of this type does. The control system seeks to make output = demand and, if there are some disturbances that cause a motor to have to drive a little harder to make output = demand then so be it. However, those disturbances are not evaluated separately within a negative feedback control system. If it were a feed-forward (note the difference) system then sure, you'd measure the disturbance and make an open-loop compensation. Your lower diagram is for a negative feedback system (not feed-forward).

Comment: @Andyaka That makes a lot of sense I see, thank you! Can I also ask you then, what it would be called if the antenna makes up for the disturbances? Would that just be classified as a "feed-forward"?

Comment: The antenna can't do anything without a control system. It is just an object that can be moved and has some form of rotary position indicator to be used by the control system.

Comment: *" A closed loop system would subtract the disturbance from the TOTAL RESPONSE (in the input) and make up for the additional two degrees."*. This statement is not correct, it should be:  A closed loop system would obtain the position error by subtracting the actual response from the required response, and would drive the system in the direction necessary to reduce the error to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken your diagram, and modified it just to show the negative feedback control system: -

[image]

Can you see that the only measurement made (red-box) is the output position.

For **disturbance 1** I've used the example of power supply noise because it can add noise or variations to the output of the control system. However, to a large degree, that variation or noise is unknown "to the system" - all that the system knows is that it may have to act against those disturbing influences.

For **disturbance 2** I've used the example of windage (the act of wind putting an extra burden on the plant). Again, those disturbing forces are not known "to the system".

Comment: Why is it not known to the system? I mean, what is the point of making a closed-loop system then? A closed-loop toaster would in example always give a delicious hot toast (output), no matter what kind of bread (input) you put/ set in the toaster. So how is the system not aware of the disturbances if it is a closed-loop system?

Comment: It doesn't need to be aware of them because it attempts to drive the error to zero and, zero error means output = demand (irrespective of other influences). A closed loop toaster would use a camera to monitor the surface colour of the bread and switch off when it's just right. If the AC mains voltage dropped to 50% (a disturbance), we don't care because the output quality is the toast colour. OK it may take longer to get the toast to the right colour of course @NemanjaVuksanovic